# Doubly Linked List of Menu Items

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I have a program which processes menu items (and submenu items) using a linkedList data structure. My program works except for the delete function which works if deleting an element inserted before an existing element but doesn't if the element is inserted after an existing element. Any advise is much appreciated! Here's the insert function

```
public Item insert(String newElem, String existingElem, int key) {
    // search for given existing element starting at head
    currentNode = new Item("");
    currentNode = head;
    while (!currentNode.element.equals(existingElem)) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        if (currentNode == null)
            break; // cannot find the given key
    }
    // create a new node
    newNode = new Item(newElem);
    if (key == 1) // if key = 1 insert after the existing element
    {
        newNode.next = currentNode.next;
        newNode.prev = currentNode;
        currentNode.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail.next = null;
        counter++;
    }
    if (key == 2) // if key = 2 insert before the existing element
    {
        newNode.next = currentNode;
        newNode.prev = currentNode.prev;
        currentNode.prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;
        head.prev = null;
        counter++;
    }
    return newNode;
}
```

I also realize that I am assuming only one existing element, however, if I could make the delete function more generic then it would be best and I don't want to split the function into multiple functions! Here's the delete function:-

```
public Item delete(String elem) {
    // search for given existing element starting at head
    currentNode = new Item("");
    currentNode = head;
    while (!currentNode.element.equals(elem)) {
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
        if (currentNode == null)
            break; // cannot find the given key
    }
    // check if element is the first element
    if (currentNode == head) {
    head = currentNode.next;
    } else {
        currentNode.prev = currentNode.next;
    }
    // check if element is the last element
    if (currentNode == tail) {
        tail = currentNode.prev;
    } else {
        currentNode = currentNode.prev;
    }
    return currentNode;
}
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel, and not using java.util.LinkedList?

Comment: It's an assignment for a data structures class to learn about the workings of linked lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems**

You should not be updating `tail` and `head` every time you insert a new node.  You should only do so if inserting at the beginning or end of the list, if you are not at the begining of the list, you need to also update the prev/next of the element that used to be before/after the one you are inserting next to:

```
if (key == 1) // if key = 1 insert after the existing element
{
    newNode.next = currentNode.next;
    newNode.prev = currentNode;
    currentNode.next = newNode;
    if (newNode.next == null)
        tail = newNode;
    else
        newNode.next.prev = newNode;
}
else if (key == 2) // if key = 2 insert before the existing element
{
    newNode.next = currentNode;
    newNode.prev = currentNode.prev;
    currentNode.prev = newNode;
    if (newNode.prev == null)
        head = newNode;
    else
        newNode.prev.next = newNode;
}
```

*Note: I am also using an* `else if` *statement, instead of two* `if`s

Your delete function need to be updated also.  You are not updating the surrounding nodes, just the one you are removing:

```
if (currentNode.prev == null) { // is head 
    head = currentNode.next;
} else {
    currentNode.prev.next = currentNode.next;
}
if (currentNode.next == null) { // is tail
    tail = currentNode.prev;
} else {
    currentNode.next.prev = currentNode.prev;
}
```

**Other comments**

It seems unusual that you would be searching for the node to insert before/after by value, what if I had a list like this: [1,2,2,2,3]? It would be impossible to insert a value in several places in that list.  Surely your API should be based on `Item`s:

```
public Item insert(String newValue, Item existingItem, int key);
public Item delete(Item item);
```

Or indicies:

```
public Item insert(String newValue, int index, int key);
public Item delete(int index);
```

You can then have another method to find the `Item` or index for a particular value:

```
public Item find(String value);
```

Or:

```
public int indexOf(String value);
```

And use them like this to get the equivalent of your methods:

```
list.insert("value", list.find("other value"), 1);
```

---

You might want to consider changing the `insert` method to an `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` method, or at least changing the `key` parameter to an enumerated type:

```
public enum Position {
    BEFORE,
    AFTER,
}
```

After all, what happens when `key` is 0, or 23?

---

You currently have `currentItem` as a class member, it should really be a local variable of the function (after all, what use does it have outside of those functions), and you also don't need to initialise it to a new element, just set it straight to `head`:

```
public Item insert(String newElem, String existingElem, int key) {
    Item currentNode = head;
    ...
}
```

---

Finally, your search code doesn't work if there are no items in the list.  The following line will fail with a `NullPointerException` if `head` is null:

```
while (!currentNode.element.equals(existingElem))
```

Because you can't call `.equals(...)` on a null reference.

Comment: Thanks Jamie....this is very helpful....yes I am handling cases where key is not 1 or 2....just not the most elegant of solutions.